# How to filter a spreadsheet on multiple filter values

Tags: spreadsheet

I've got a spreadsheet of addresses with the following columns: First Name, Last Name, Street Address, City, State, and zip code.  I'd like to be able to filter or otherwise extract a subset of these address records based on a set of geographically close postal codes.  We've been using http://www.freemaptools.com/find-zip-codes-inside-radius.htm to get a list of codes that are within a certain radius of the targe area.  W

What's the easiest way to take the comma separated list of zipcodes from freemapstools.com to get a subset of addresses from the full mailing list spreadsheet?

For example: from our complete list of addresses, I want to see all addresses that have a zipcode in the set of: "55055,55119,55125,55129"

For what it's worth, we're using Google Docs, but if this would be easier in Excel that would be fine too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers.  Both suggestions work great if we're only trying to filter by a few zipcodes at a time.  However, it's not uncommon for us to have a subset of 20 or 30 different zipcodes for an area.  Manually checking or selecting those zipcodes one at a time is not very easy or fast.  I'm hoping for a faster solution.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly too late to help the poster, but since searching is demanded before asking a question it must be desirable to have useful answers to old questions.

Available since Excel 2007 is the "Advanced Filter" functionality.

To use it, one constructs a criteria range using headers from the data range's columns. (Copying and pasting those ensures no mistakes are made in that.) That criteria range can be any size. It requires entries like `= "=32000"` so just pasting a list of, say, Zip Codes into it won't work out, but one could set up a constructer range outside it that lets one paste the 20-30 values and copy a column of formula produced strings with the `'=` prepended and the `"` appended, then paste THOSE into the criteria range.

AF's output would then include valid results for all those Zip Codes ("OR" logic) with just the two pastes. No checking one at a time, or running down a list using the regular column Filter feature and checking one at a time.

Useful as anything, but about as known as the "database" functions (`DSUM`, `Detc`) which are also quite handy. Looks like it's just a formalization of that set of functions, but who knows. In any case, it would do the job described above without much in the way of difficulty. One could even write a little macro that you activate right after pasting the list in the constructor and it would do the needed Copy and Paste. And if one were able to write VBA rather than use the VBA Recorder, one could paste right in the criteria range and run the macro which would add the extra characters to make them strings AF can use.

Answer (score 0):

In your google doc spreadsheet, go to `Data->Filter`.  Click on the boxed down arrow that appears in the header of the zip column.  Click on "clear", then type in your desired zipcodes and click on them when they come up (they should be checked).

Comment: I'm hoping there's a faster method as we often have 20+ zipcodes we'd like to filter by.  typing and checking them one-by-one is pretty tedious.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2007 and 2010 the filter options use checkboxes on all applicable values to allow custom selection of any given combination for any given filtered column.

Instead of being presented with a list of the possible values and then whichever you select you get those filtered, such as in Office version 2003 and before, you get a series of checkboxes in 2007 and later. This is less efficient for those times that you only want one particular value, but it's much more powerful in the custom selection capability.

Comment: I'm hoping there's a faster method as we often have 20+ zipcodes we'd like to filter by.  Checking them one-by-one is pretty tedious.

Comment: Yes it is. I assume it wouldn't be too difficult to write a macro that allows you to enter zip codes you wish to filter by. The current system is definitely an improvement from before, though it's more "average user"-friendly than it is "advanced user"-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following - which uses a formula to filter, rather than the column's filter drop-down.

Cell `F3` contains `=FILTER(A3:A8, MATCH(A3:A8, D3:D5, 0))` where `A` contains the complete list of data, and `D` contains the subset used to filter.

Note that in Google Sheets, you just need to complete cell `F3`. `F4` (and onwards) will automatically fill with the remaining results. Updating the filter output is easy - just edit column `D`.

I've included it in a single view for the sake of the screenshot below, however in practice I would put the output (columns `F:G`) in a separate sheet to delineate the two sets.

See [Google Docs Help page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) for further info on the Filter function.

[image: Filter Match example]

Comment: Is there a similar solution for this in MS Excel 2013. This works for 2019 only. :(